# Updating elements inside of an array within a BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a "Payee" BsonDocument like this:

```
{
  "Token" : "0b21ae960f25c6357286ce6c206bdef2",
  "LastAccessed" : ISODate("2012-07-11T02:14:59.94Z"),
  "Firstname" : "John",
  "Lastname" : "Smith",
  "PayrollInfo" : [{
      "Tag" : "EARNINGS",
      "Value" : "744.11",
    }, {
      "Tag" : "DEDUCTIONS",
      "Value" : "70.01",
    }],
  },
  "Status" : "1",
  "_id" : ObjectId("4fc263158db2b88f762f1aa5")
}
```

I retrieve this document based on the Payee _id.

```
var collection = database.GetCollection("Payee");
var query = Query.EQ("_id", _id);
var bDoc = collection.FindOne(query);
```

Then, at various times I need to update a specific object inside the PayrollInfo array.  So I search for the object with appropriate "Tag" inside the array and update the "Value" into the database.  I use the following logic to do this:

```
var bsonPayrollInfo = bDoc["PayrollInfo", null];
if (bsonPayrollInfo != null)
{
    var ArrayOfPayrollInfoObjects = bsonPayrollInfo.AsBsonArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < ArrayOfPayrollInfoObjects.Count; i++)
    {
        var bInnerDoc = ArrayOfPayrollInfoObjects[i].AsBsonDocument;
        if (bInnerDoc != null)
        {
            if (bInnerDoc["Tag"] == "EARNINGS")
            {
                //update here
                var update = Update
                    .Set("PayrollInfo."+ i.ToString() + ".Value", 744.11)
                collection.FindAndModify(query, null, update);
                bUpdateData = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

if (!bUpdateData)
{
    //Use Update.Push.  This works fine and is not relevant to the question.
}
```

All this code works fine, but I think I am being cumbersome in achieving the result.  Is there a more concise way of doing this?  Essentially, I am trying to find a better way of updating an object inside of an array in a BsonDocument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo has a positional operator that will let you operate on the matched value in an array. The syntax is: `field1.$.field2`

Here's an example of how you'd use it from the Mongo shell:

```
db.dots.insert({tags: [{name: "beer", count: 2}, {name: "nuts", count: 3}]})
db.dots.update({"tags.name": "beer"}, {$inc: {"tags.$.count" : 1}})
result = db.dots.findOne()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50078284ea80325278ff0c63"), "tags" : [ { "name" : "beer", "count" : 3 }, { "name" : "nuts", "count" : 3 } ] }
```

Comment: I see the use of positional operator when I am directly querying on the array element, but in my case I have a Bsondocument through the _id query.  I need to find the array element in this document that I already have in hand.  My original code shown above works fine.  But I think I may be missing a better approach to the problem.

Comment: You can skip all the C# and just issue an update, though, even if you already have the doc. Just make the query something like: {_id: [ID], "PayrollInfo.Tag": "EARNINGS"} and send that positional operator through as the update doc.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  You helped me look in the right places for implementing via positional operator.

Answer (score 1):

Putting my answer here in case it helps you.  Based on @MrKurt's answer (thank you!), here is what I did to rework the code.

```
var collection = database.GetCollection("Payee");
var query = Query.EQ("_id", _id);

if (collection.Count(query) > 0)
{
    //Found the Payee.  Let's save his/her Tag for EARNINGS
    UpdateBuilder update = null;

    //Check if this Payee already has any EARNINGS Info saved.
    //If so, we need to update that.
    query = Query.And(query,
        Query.EQ("PayrollInfo.Tag", "EARNINGS"));

    //Update will be written based on whether we find the Tag:EARNINGS element in the PayrollInfo array
    if (collection.Count(query) > 0)
    {
        //There is already an element in the PayrollInfo for EARNINGS
        //Just update that element
        update = Update
            .Set("PayrollInfo.$.Value", "744.11");
    }
    else
    {
        //This user does not have any prior EARNINGS data.  Add it to the user record
        query = Query.EQ("_id", _id);
        //Add a new element in the Array for PayrollInfo to store the EARNINGS data
        update = Update.Push("PayrollInfo",
                    new BsonDocument {{"Tag", "EARNINGS"}, {"Value", "744.11"}}
                 ); 
    }

    //Run the update
    collection.FindAndModify(query, null, update);
}
```

It doesn't look any lesser than my original code, but it is much more intuitive, and I got to learn a lot about positional operators!